# How to post form data to a server expecting a regular HTML form using angular reactive?

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript, http

I'm replacing a static form that sends data to an old perl script with an angular reactive form. I can't figure out how to format the form data and send it using `HttpClient.post`. A lot of examples I'm seeing for posting this way actually create the data object in the request itself, not coming from an actual form, so I'm stumped

I've tried posting the data as just the form, as JSON (I'm not sure the server is expecting JSON, it's really old), sending the form's data object in the controller

the original static form `<form>` tag:

```html
<form id="HTML_FORM"  method="POST" role="form" action="https://sos.cnm.edu/MRcgi/MRProcessIncomingForms.pl" >
```

This was just submitted using a regular HTML submit input, and that works fine.

My new template:

```html
<form [formGroup]="opieForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="TITLE" formControlName="TITLE" #TITLE placeholder="required" >
...
<button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!opieForm.valid" type="submit">Submit form</button>
</form>
```

The controller (parts)

```js
opieForm: FormGroup;
httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
})};

this.opieForm = this.fb.group({
      TITLE: [ '', Validators.required ],
      // lots of other inputs
})

onSubmit = () => {
    console.warn(this.opieForm.value);
    return this.http.post('https://sos.cnm.edu/MRcgi/MRProcessIncomingForms.pl', this.opieForm.value, this.httpOptions)
      .subscribe(res => console.log(res), error => console.error(error));
  }
```

The `console.warn(this.opieForm.value);` produces output:

```
{TITLE: "test", First__bName: "test", Last__bName: "test", Email__bAddress: "test@test.com", dateNeeded: {…}, …}
```

The error that's returned

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "https://sos.cnm.edu/MRcgi/MRProcessIncomingForms.pl", ok: false, …}
error: {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHtt…, text: "<!DOCTYPE>↵ <HTML>↵ <!-- FP VERSION: 11.6.04 -->↵↵…ipt language = "javascript">self.close()</script>"}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
message: "Http failure during parsing for https://sos.cnm.edu/MRcgi/MRProcessIncomingForms.pl"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
url: "https://sos.cnm.edu/MRcgi/MRProcessIncomingForms.pl"
```

Error text:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0↵    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)↵    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:7639:51)↵    at ZoneDelegate.push.
...
```

When the form submits correctly it redirects to a success page and sends an email.

Comment: It seems that the endpoint?API is not returning a JSON.

Comment: If you have to change the response type, check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49319272/angular-5-httpclient-observe-and-responsetype-blob you can send a responseType in the request's headers.

Comment: I'm not sure the terms endpoint or API existed when this script was written. It's an old POS. But it works. 

How would I know what responseType is necessary? What responseType does a static form send? Not to be confused with Content-Type?

Comment: Inspect it via browser's console or using a tool like Postman to query the endpoint and inspect the response.

Comment: `Postman returns Content-Type →text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding →gzip
ETag →""
Vary →Accept-Encoding
Server →Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Date →Mon, 15 Apr 2019 16:11:23 GMT
Connection →close`
@ChristianBenseler

Comment: So it explains: the endpoint does not return a json. You have to change the request, ni the Angular application, to query this content-type (because the default is JSON) and then parse the data in a proper way.

Comment: I set `responseType: 'text'` and no longer received errors. I couldn't tell if the error was coming from the server or if angular was complaining that it couldn't parse what was coming back from the server, but now I know it was the latter. I also changed the `Accept` to `text/html, application/xhtml+xml, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8` but I'm not sure if that made a difference. Thanks @ChristianBenseler